# Disable keyboard popup java Dialog in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, emulation

How to **disable** keyboard popup when my dialog.show(); ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uynn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the keyboard if you add this code in your dialog's OnCreate:

```
getActivity()
    .getWindow()
    .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```